# Partial derivative with integration and the partial derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let the $f(x,y)$ be a symmetric function where $x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1]$ and $f(x,y)\in[0,1].$

The question is whether the following statement is valid.

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy >0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} >0
\end{equation}

If its not, could anyone gives me a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify whether the inequality is supposed to hold for all values of $x$. But, assuming you meant that, try
$$f(x,y) = \frac34(x+y)-xy.$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Once you're satisfied that this has answered your question, you should accept the answer so that the question goes off the unanswered list. :) Of course, feel free to follow up with questions until you're satisfied.